# Comma separated value

Tags: c

I want to create a .CSV file which I can open with Excel and do some math with them. The problem is that I can't locate the numbers in different cells in the table. I use \t symbol to separate them into different cells but it doesn't happen. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("File/test.csv", "w+");
    fprintf(fp,"%d \t%d\n",100,200);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

With this code I get two numbers (100 & 200) in same cell. How can I distribute all the numbers in the separated cells (one next to another)?

Comment: CSV ... "use `\t` symbol"...

Comment: Hint - CSV = comma separated values. If you don't change the default behavior of excel, you need to separate the values with a comma.

Comment: Or change it to actually be comma separated rather than tab delimited - `fprintf(fp,"%d,%d\n",100,200);`

Comment: Do you mean "character separated value" file? Formally, that's what Excel handles. Is the delimiter *really* a tab? If it's a comma, then do you have quoted strings with commas? That makes parsing harder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS DOS standard uses ';'.

Use it instead of '\t'

Comment: @user3789035 So when will yo click on the "Accept" check mark then?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `,` symbol to separate data into cells:

```
fprintf(fp,"%d,%d\n",100,200);
//            ^
```